# How to clear Job logs on IBM mid range machine

Tags: ibm-midrange, jobs

We have jobs running on our AS/400, but then randomly our session or job just ends. We have determine that a job reaches the maxim job messages and then end the Job.

Is there a way to clear the job logs, while the the job is running?

Comment: You may also want to analyze whether this many messages is caused by some problem that should be fixed.

Comment: @WarrenT Yes we do, but most messages are just informing us that the functions are doing what we expect.

Comment: BTW,  technically speaking, you probably don't have an AS/400.  IBM hasn't sold those since 2000. You most likely have an iSeries or a Power System running IBM i (or i5/OS if you are on a release prior to 6.1)

Comment: mmmm... well I am not so clued up on this, but I think it could be the iSeries.

Comment: Well when the AS/400 was introduced, the best PC's still ran on 386 chips.  I sometimes tell .NET people, don't call my server an AS/400 and I won't call yours a PS/2 ;-)

Comment: I understand ;) just around the work place, this is the server's common name.  And did not question it.

Comment: I don't know about your shop, but we are very happy to be running on Power7 hardware. The same state-of-the-art stuff that Watson runs on. A far cry from AS/400 systems in 1988.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the system value `QJOBMSGQFL` to `*WRAP` so that the messages will wrap around to the beginning when it fills.

```
CHGSYSVAL SYSVAL(QJOBMSGQFL) VALUE(*WRAP)
```

Alternatively you can change it on a specific job description.  For example:

```
CHGJOBD JOBD(QDFTJOBD) JOBMSGQFL(*WRAP)
```

[Jobs system values: When maximum size is reached](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzakz/rzakzqjobmsgqfl.htm)

Comment: There sould be a second 'S' in `CHGSYVAL` it should be `CHGSYSVAL`.  Just in case someone can't get this working ;)